# How to get rid of this error i.e Assignments can only happen to writable values in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_programs\function.php

Tags: php, postgresql, variable-assignment

Getting a error in php as **Fatal error: Assignments can only happen to writable values in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_programs\function.php on line 9.** The variable $data['status'] is not able intialize any  value. I want intialize it false keyword.

````
 ```
<?php
require 'gp.php';
function registeruser($userdata){
$con=$GLOBALs['$db'];   
$data=array();
if($userdata['email_id']==' '){
$error++;
$data=['status']=false;   //this is the line where im getting error
$data=['message']='Enter your Email id!';
}

if($userdata['full_name']==' '){
$error++;
$data=['status']=false; 
$data=['message']='Enter your Full name!';

}
if($userdata['password']==' '){

$error++;
$data=['status']=false;
$data=['message']='Enter your Password!';
}

if($error>0){
return $data;
}

$full_name=pg_escape_string($con,$userdata['full_name']);
$email_id=pg_escape_string($con,$userdata['email_id']);
$password=pg_escape_string($con,$userdata['password']);

$query="INSERT INTO users(user_id,full_name,email_id,password)";
$query.="VALUES('$user_id','$full_name','$email_id','$password')";

if(pg_query($con,$data)){
$data=['status']=true;
$data=['message']='Account created!';

}
else{
$data['status']=false;
$data['message']='Something is wrong';

}

return $data;

}

?> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's how you assign array variable.
Instead of `$data=['status']=false`
It should be `$data['status']=false`

Hope this help.